# Book or series with golems, djinni, and magic artifacts like orbs

Tags: story-identification

Probably close to 13 or 10 years since I've read it.  But I cannot remember the name or author.

What I can remember is that it's a magic series, set in London.  Based on magic artifacts like orbs that are and do different things and I think it's about a guy who buys them or has a shop.  I remember there being golems and djinni in it also.

I do remember specifically about a golem being full of Scrolls or scripts if that helps?

I wish I knew more as it was a favorite.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. I hope you decide to stick around!

Comment: Is it possible that it has something to do with a novelization of *Huntik*? All elements are there: amulets, Prague, Golem etc. http://huntik.wikia.com/wiki/The_Golem_of_Prague

Comment: At first I thought it was [Feet of clay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feet_of_Clay_(novel)) (a golem full of scrolls in a London-like city), but since you also mentioned Prague, it is imposible to be set on the Discworld. Best of lucks in your search! :)

Answer (score 12):

Could this be the '[Bartimaeus Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartimaeus_Sequence)' of books by Jonathan Stroud, starting with *The Amulet of Samarkand* (2003)?

It's set in London, there are djinni, golems, magical orbs and other such artifacts.

> The first book in the series, published 2003, introduces Nathaniel as
>   the gifted 12-year-old apprentice of a middle-aged mid-level magician,
>   Arthur Underwood. He assumes his magician name, John Mandrake, to
>   protect him from rivals who would wish to harm him. When the magician
>   Simon Lovelace cruelly humiliates Nathaniel in public, Nathaniel
>   decides to take revenge by stealing Lovelace's most powerful
>   possession, the Amulet of Samarkand. The Amulet makes the wearer
>   invulnerable to magical (but not physical) attack. Unknown to his
>   tutor, he begins the study of advanced magic in order to summon the
>   djinni Bartimaeus and enslave him. Bartimaeus soon overhears
>   Nathaniel's birth-name, which greatly reduces Nathaniel's control over
>   him, because demons can then cast counterspells. Things soon get out
>   of hand and Bartimaeus and Nathaniel find themselves caught in the
>   middle of magical espionage, murder, blackmail, and revolt. Together,
>   the two of them defeat Lovelace and his most powerful demon, Ramuthra,
>   who was last seen destroying an entire nation. These actions ended an
>   uneasy truce between the young magician and Bartimaeus, resulting in
>   the demon returning to whence he came.

Comment: I also remember there being alot of Prague in the series.  Is this in that series?  Also a golem filled with various Scrolls from different masters over centuries?

Comment: Prague is mentioned; http://bartimaeus.wikia.com/wiki/Prague

Comment: This sounds right, especially with the Prague references.  I barely remember this series, but golems, djinni, London, magic artifacts, and even some vague memory of Prague all tie in to what I remember.  If there's another series with all that it would be a large coincidence.

Comment: When I read the title on the hot network questions I came here to post this too. I think it fits nicely

Answer (score 6):

As Valorum has already [said](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/160520/31394), this is almost certainly the Bartimaeus series. However, since (I think) Valorum hasn't read these books himself and is only going by online descriptions, I thought it'd be worth having a more detailed answer based on knowledge of the books.

> Probably close to 13 or 10 years since I've read it.

The series consists of three books published **between 2003 and 2005** (not counting the 2010 spin-off novel set several thousand years earlier).

> it's a magic series, set in London.

The entire series is set **in or around London**, except for a chunk in the middle of the second book when the protagonists visit Prague (on which more later).

> Based on magic artifacts like orbs that are and do different things

Much of the magic in the series is actually based on the power of spirits/demons, who can be summoned by magicians (with appropriate rituals) and bound to do their will. The main protagonist, Bartimaeus himself, is one of these. However, humans can also perform acts of power more directly using magical artifacts, elemental **orbs** being a low-level example, which only work because of spirits trapped inside them.

> and I think it's about a guy who buys them or has a shop.

Sholto Pinn is a rich London magician - one of very few magicians we meet who aren't part of the government, which in this series is composed entirely of (backstabbing) magicians - and the proprietor of **Pinn's Emporium**, a swanky shop full of magical artifacts. We visit this shop briefly in book 1 before it's destroyed by a golem early in book 2.

> I remember there being golems and djinni in it also.

Bartimaeus himself is a **fourth-level djinni**, and we meet various other djinn throughout the series too: notably Faquarl, an old adversary of Bartimaeus who keeps cropping up. The main plot of the second book is about a **golem** wreaking devastation in London, and the government's attempts to find its master and destroy it.

> I also remember there being alot of Prague in the series.

In book 2, Bartimaeus and his master (the secondary protagonist - secret real name Nathaniel, official name John Mandrake) pay a visit to **Prague**, the origin of golems, in order to try to find who's controlling the one in London. They must act undercover, as Prague is an old enemy of Britain, and despite being conquered by William Gladstone (a very powerful magician) in the 19th century, tension between the two states is still high.